# About PHP's variable call-by-value and call-value-reference

Tags: php

I have a question regarding the way PHP handles variables value assignment.

we have the following statement:

```
$myVariable = "value";
```

The above statement assigns a value to variable `$myVariable` and then allocates a memory location to it.

But if we add the following statement to the above script:

```
$secondVariable = $myVariable;
```

Then:

Regarding performance issues it is suggested to avoid duplicate values and keep using referencing if the value is not about to be changed (C++, Dietel & Dietel's famous book How to Program in C++)

But what about PHP? I have heard, just heard, that PHP does some tricks and manages such duplications (`$secondVariable = $myVarible`) by calling-by-reference than by value and do not duplicate the variable untill some changes happens to $secondVariable and after that a duplication is made.

Conclusion:

```
$myVariable = "value";

$secondVariable = $myVariable;
```

Is something like this in C++:

```
string myVariable = "value";

string secondVariable = &myVariable;
```

Though I know PHP is written in C, C++ is a close heir of C.

Can anyone tells if the above conclusion is correct and if PHP manages variables like this or it does not care and like `C&C++` creates a new memory location on each value-assignment?

Comment: Are you trying to microoptimize something specific, with actual reason? References in PHP are not akin to pointers in C.

Comment: Short answer - PHP won't allocate twice the memory for the example you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little bit different.
You can also use pointer to a reference in PHP :

```
$a = &$b ;
```

If you modify $a, you also modify $b (and vice versa) because it's the same memory address that is referenced.

When you do this :

```
$a = 'something' ;
$b = $a ;
```

$b is managed as a copy of $a. Both variables are independent. BUT, until you modify $b (or $a), PHP only store a reference to $a. This is why, until you modify $a or $b, you only have one quantity of RAM which is used.

To be sure about that, you can use the function "memory_get_usage" and make your tests :

```
[dcordel:~] master+ ± php /tmp/test-1.php 

$aVar = str_repeat('a', 268435456);
$another = &$aVar ;
Mem : 256 Mo

[dcordel:~] master+ ± php /tmp/test-2.php 
$aVar = str_repeat('a', 268435456);
$another = str_repeat('a', 268435456);
Mem : 512 Mo

[dcordel:~] master+ ± php /tmp/test-3.php     
$aVar = str_repeat('a', 268435456);
$another = $aVar ;
//before
$another.= 'a' ;
//after

before update : Mem : 256 Mo
after update :  Mem : 512 Mo
```